# How to access node.js from outside of local network (LAN)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-server-2003

I am running a node.js application on the server and it runs fine on the localhost but I cannot access it remotely from other systems outside of my LAN.

This is mainly because there is a router between my server (Windows Server 2003) and the Internet which does not allow Port 3000 to be open.

So I want to listen on port 80 but if the request is for a specific URL, I want to redirect it to port 3000.

How do I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Share the node.js code that runs the server. Did you listen on ip 0.0.0.0?

Comment: And if you want to proxy port 80 to port 3000 on the software side, I don't think Node can do that. You'll need an Apache or nginx service to redirect the request

Comment: @cricket_007 Node can definitely do that, although it would need to run as root to bind to a privileged port. It could then use `process.setuid` to downgrade and continue running as a normal user, the same way Apache and Nginx do.

Comment: @Paulpro - Hmm. Good to know. Still, I wouldn't want a web service running as a privileged user

Comment: @cricket_007 That's why the downgrade is important. It would downgrade during startup initialization before it actually starts handling any requests, just like any other web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your Webserver (IIS) to listen for external connections on Port 80 and (proxy) forward this to the Node Server at Port 3000. Windows 2003 is EOL (end of software lifecylce), so keep that in mind. For more mature IT infrastructure like Linux and nginx, DigitalOcean wrote [this great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04), you can run nginx on Windows.

Comment: Thanks this is the closest thing to my solution!